# Some facts about the chameleophant please

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Can you give me some facts (where it lives, their size etc.) about the chameleophant?

Can't find it on google...
[image: enter image description here... idk]

Comment: I do not think you posted the question in good faith BTW, a simple google image search for "chameleophant" or a reverse search using the image will lead you to the website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the place to post jokes, although I hesitantly admit I almost liked this post. Almost.

Comment: @AliceD I like your name

Comment: Kind of fits your image doesn't it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It does not exist. It is a photoshopped image. This is the original image which was used to create it:
[image: source image]

It is listed on some websites with other photoshopped images, such as this one:
https://www.planetacurioso.com/2013/05/27/como-serian-los-animales-combinados-con-otros/

Comment: Okay thank you but why doesn't it exist?

Comment: @Squareoot Because evolution favors practical bodies. Look at the poor bugger, how would it shoot out its tongue at an insect if there was a trunk in the way? Duh...

Comment: +1 because you somehow managed to find the original pic. Clever. However, in the future, please flag this sort of questions and refrain from answering, as it encourages other users to post similar crap.